# Event operating on control in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, file, download, progress-bar

I have some files to download from ftp server. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. There's a `SplitContainer`, with `ListView` in one of the panels on the `MainForm`.
2. I want to get file list to download, create a `ProgressBar` and a `Label` for each file in that `ListView`
3. In the `ProgressChanged` event, I want to display the current progress of a file on the `ProgressBar` and current download speed on the `Label`

This is the latest version of my code:

```
internal async Task GetFiles(IEnumerable<string> urlList)
{
    string dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\updates";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var url in urlList)
        tasks.Add(DownloadFile(url, dir));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

internal async Task DownloadFile(string url, string dir)
{
    string filename = Helper.GetFilenameFromUrl(url);
    ProgressBar pb = CreateFileDownloadBar();
    Label lb = CreateFileDownloadLabel();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.listView1.Controls.Add(pb));
    Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.listView1.Controls.Add(lb));

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw, pb, lb));
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw));
        Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.lblFileDownload.Text = Helper.GetFilenameFromUrl(url));
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, string.Concat(dir, "\\", filename));
    }
}

private Label CreateFileDownloadLabel()
{
    Label lb = new Label()
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(_sender.offset - 180, 5 + offset)
    };
    return lb;
}

private ProgressBar CreateFileDownloadBar()
{
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar()
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5 + offset),
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
    };

    offset += pb.Height + 5;

    return pb;
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw, ProgressBar pb, Label lb)
{
    pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    lb.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));        
}
```

However, `pb` and `lb` in that event do not update controls on `MainForm`. I suspect it's because I operate on the local copies of it, not the ones I added to `MainForm`, but I have no idea how to make it work. Do I need some kind of counter to `CrossThreadInvoke` something like

```
ProgressBar pb = Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.listView1.Controls[counter] as ProgressBar;
pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

However, this seems needlessly complicated, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Add a `pb.Update();` after setting the new value and see if that helps

Comment: @lokusking nope it didn't, sadly

Comment: I overread that part where you're telling that you already have Controls on your MainForm. For sure, you have to update those Controls, and not the ones you are creating but never showing. You can do it the other way round too. Leave your existing code untouched, remove the controls from your MainForm and replace them with the ones you are creating in the download-logic

Comment: @lokusking Ye, but to show them on `MainForm` I need to add them before I start doing any updating. So even if I just leave the split container there as part of main form (since the other half contains controls for it), do all my listview, progressbars and what-not in the other class, I still need to add them back to the `MainForm` as whole, before any updating. Wich I think leaves me back at square one.

Comment: Hard to tell, what is the best practice in your case without knowing the full code.

Comment: @lokusking the rest of the code is main form with diesgner-dropped split container and listview on it, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a small example which is really not pretty but should give you an idea how to realize the progress things.

Also i've commented a lot of things out and inserted some Demo-Code.

The key is to use Controls.Invoke()-Method if you are on diffrent threads / Tasks.

**Example**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {


    public Form1() {

      InitializeComponent();
      var l = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        l.Add("Some Text" + i);
      }
      Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await GetFiles(l, this);
      });
    }



    private int ctrlCount = 0;

    public void AddControlToListView(Control c) {
      if (c is Label) {
        c.Location = new Point(205, ctrlCount * c.Height + 5);
      } else {
        c.Location = new Point(5, ctrlCount * c.Height + 5);
      }

      if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired) {
        this.listView1.Invoke(new Action<Control>(this.listView1.Controls.Add), c);
        this.listView1.Invoke(new Action(this.listView1.Update));
      } else {
        this.listView1.Controls.Add(c);
        this.listView1.Update();
      }

      ctrlCount++;
    }

    internal async Task GetFiles(IEnumerable<string> urlList, Form1 parent) {
      //string dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\updates";

      //Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
      var tasks = new List<Task>();

      foreach (var url in urlList)
        tasks.Add(DownloadFile(url, ""));

      await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }



    internal async Task DownloadFile(string url, string dir) {
      string filename = "";// Helper.GetFilenameFromUrl(url);
      ProgressBar pb = CreateFileDownloadBar();
      Label lb = CreateFileDownloadLabel();
      this.AddControlToListView(pb);
      this.AddControlToListView(lb);
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      //Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.listView1.Controls.Add(pb));
      //Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.listView1.Controls.Add(lb));
      await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
          pb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            pb.Value = i * 10;
          }));
          lb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            lb.Text = (i * 10).ToString();
          }));
          Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
      });
      using (var client = new WebClient()) {
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw, pb, lb));
        //client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw));
        //Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(_sender, () => _sender.lblFileDownload.Text = Helper.GetFilenameFromUrl(url));
        //await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, string.Concat(dir, "\\", filename));
      }
    }

    private Label CreateFileDownloadLabel() {
      Label lb = new Label() {
        Text = "Hello"
        //Location = new System.Drawing.Point(_sender.offset - 180, 5 + offset)
      };
      return lb;
    }

    private ProgressBar CreateFileDownloadBar() {
      ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar() {
        //Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5 + offset),
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
      };

      //offset += pb.Height + 5;

      return pb;
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw, ProgressBar pb, Label lb) {
      pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
      lb.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
    }  

}
```

I hope this gives you an idea on how to create and update your ProgressBars